# fullcalendar header locale language not changing on angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am working in a project using angular 8 and fullcalendar component. My problem is that when the locale changes the header buttons remain in English.

My html:

```
<full-calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [events]="displayedEvents" locale="fr"
      [header]="{
      right: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      left: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
      }">
</full-calendar>
```

The .ts file is a little complicated to post but I've read [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4581) and in their [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale) that I need to import the `locale-all.js` file but that does not work. In either case I get this error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@fullcalendar/core/locales-all.js'. 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/locales-all.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

The file exists but it seems that the compiler searches a `.d.ts` declaration file.

Thank you

Comment: Did you add this file to the import in the `angular.json`? Also, can you please add to your question your `tsconfig.json`?